# How to send multiple image files using sockets?

Tags: python, image, sockets, server, client

The below code only sends the first image file. How can I send multiple images?

**Server side code:**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("", 12345))
bind to ('', port)
s.listen(10)
c, addr = s.accept()
print('{} connected.'.format(addr))

m = c.recv(1024)
m1 = c.recv(1024)
f = open(r"C:\python voice\haha3.jpg", "wb")
f1 = open(r"C:\python voice\haha4.jpg", "wb")
data = None
data1 = None

while True:
    data = m
    data1 = m1
    if m:
        while m:
            m = c.recv(1024)
            data += m
        else:
            break
    if m1:
        while m1:
            m1 = c.recv(1024)
            data1 += m1
        else:
            break

f.write(data)
f.close()
f1.write(data1)
f1.close()

print("Done receiving")
```

**Client side code:**

```
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",12345))
f = open(r"C:\python voice\image.jpg", "rb")
l = os.path.getsize(r"C:\python voice\image.jpg")
m = f.read(l)
s.send(m)
f.close()
print("Done sending...")

f1 = open(r"C:\python voice\image1.jpg", "rb")
l1 = os.path.getsize(r"C:\python voice\image1.jpg")
m1 = f1.read(l1)
s.send(m1)
f1.close()
print("Done sending...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a plain TCP protocol.

This is a transport protocol. It deals with generic streams of bytes.

You have to use or invent an application protocol that knows what files are.

Example: before sending the file send a header describing how many files will follow and their sizes in bytes. With that info you can reconstruct the files from the stream

Comment: This seems to implement a simple framing protocol https://thoslin.github.io/build-a-simple-protocol-over-tcp/